# How to make a software simulation available

Tags: simulation

I wish to make a software simulation available such that users can edit the source code and experiment with it. The IO of the software is simple text printing (no graphics). I don't mind too much what language it is, so long as it's not too unusual. My main criteria is that users can be up and running as quickly as possible on as many devices as possible without too much complicated set up.

One possibility is that there may be some website somewhere which allows you to cut and paste some source code into a window and it will run online in you browser... I have seen sites that do this kind of thing for html and javascript... maybe there is a site that handles BASIC or C or Java?

The other possibility is to use a language for which there is a small-free-simple compiler available for multiple OS's.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Oops, I forgot - it would be even better if the program could also take input strings from the user at runtime.

Comment: Check out http://codepad.org

Comment: @ Ahmed Masud: Looks good - you should put that as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codepad will do the trick for you.

http://codepad.org

Ahh! well http://ideone.com supports sscanf() etc.

Comment: This looks very good - but I forgot to mention (see edit to OP) that it would be even better if the simulation could accept user input at runtime. I just tried getch() in the 'C' language and got a compilation error... can codepad run code which demands user input?

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer an alternative solution - I just discovered the [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/) (Tint C Compiler). Its incredibly small and easy to use. Its comes in a 274k zip file you just unpack, then run in a DOS box with a command like:

```
c:\<path to where you unpacked the compiler>\tcc yoursource.c
```

this produces yoursource.exe and you're ready to run.